# Error: Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The source height is 0

Tags: javascript

I Have Been Working In a Project For Last 2 Days And This One Error Is Very Irritating Me I Cant Get Rid Of it Whenever I UnComment the canvas.style Its Throwing The Error

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The source height is 0.
```

When I Am Commenting the canvas.style Its Shows The half text Click On The Link To See the Image Preview
[click image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFN9y.png)

what can I Do For it

This is the Code If Anyone knows the ans. pls. let me know

this is the Text class

```
export class Text {
    constructor() {
        this.canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        // this.canvas.style.position = 'absolute';
        // this.canvas.style.left = '0';
        // this.canvas.style.top = '0';
        document.body.appendChild(this.canvas);

        // this.style = this.canvas.style;
        // this.style.position = 'absolute';

        this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
    }

    setText(str, density, stageWidth, stageHeight) {
        this.canvas.width = stageWidth;
        this.canvas.height = stageHeight;

        const myText = str;
        const fontWidth = 700;
        const fontSize = 800;
        const fontName = 'Hind';

        this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, stageWidth, stageHeight);
        this.ctx.font = `${fontWidth} ${fontSize}px ${fontName}`;
        this.ctx.fillStyle = `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)`;
        this.ctx.textBaseline = `middle`;
        const fontPos = this.ctx.measureText(myText);
        this.ctx.fillText(
            myText,
            (stageWidth - fontPos.width) / 2,
            fontPos.actualBoundingBoxAscent +
            fontPos.actualBoundingBoxDescent + 
            ((stageHeight - fontSize) / 2)
        );

        return this.dotPos(density, stageWidth, stageHeight);
    }

    dotPos(density, stageWidth, stageHeight) {
        const imageData = this.ctx.getImageData(
            0, 0,
            stageWidth, stageHeight
        ).data;

        const particles = [];
        let i = 0;
        let width = 0;
        let pixel;

        for (let height = 0; height < stageHeight; height += density) {
            ++i;
            const slide = (i % 2) == 0;
            width = 0;
            if (slide ==1) {
                width += 6;
            }

            for (width = 0; width < stageWidth; width += density) {
                pixel = imageData[((width + (height*stageWidth)) * 4) - 1];
                if (pixel != 0 && 
                    width > 0 && 
                    width < stageWidth && 
                    height > 0 && 
                    height < stageHeight) {
                    particles.push({
                        x: width,
                        y: height,
                    });
                }
            }
        }

        return particles;
    }
}
```

this is the App module

```
import {Text} from './text.js'

class App {
  constructor() {  

    WebFont.load({
      google: {
        families: ['Hind:700']
      },
      fontactive: () => {
        this.text = new Text();
        this.text.setText(
          'A',
          2,
          document.body.clientWidth,
          document.body.clientHeight,
        );
      }
    });
  
  }
}

window.onload = () => {
  new App();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because before you insert anything to your `<body>`, its `.clientHeight` will return `0`, since its actual CSS `height` is `auto` and it has no content that takes any height.

```js
console.log( document.body.clientHeight ); // 0
document.body.append( document.createElement( "canvas" ) );
console.log( document.body.clientHeight ); // 150
```

```css
canvas { display: block }
```

I guess you wanted your canvas to be as big as the current page, in that case what you want is `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` (and don't forget to add a `body{ margin: 0; }` and a  `display: block` rule to not have the line-height come into play).

```js
const canvas = document.createElement( "canvas" );
onresize = (evt) => {
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  const ctx = canvas.getContext( "2d" );
  ctx.fillStyle = "green";
  ctx.fillRect( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
  document.body.append( canvas );
};
onresize();
```

```css
body { margin: 0 }
canvas { display: block }
```